# Declaring object property types before destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-types

Let's assume there's a function that returns an object whose property types can either be inferred or are explicitly provided:

```
const myFn = (arg: number) => {
    return {
        a: 1 + arg,
        b: 'b' + arg,
        c: (() => { return arg + 'c'})()
    }
}
```

We can then destructure the returned object and assign to new variables:

```
const { a, b, c } = myFn(10);
console.log('used once', a, b, c);
```

All nice and dandy. Now let's assume we'll need to reassign to those same variables later on, more specifically in a switch statement. In order to prevent `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'xyz'. ts(2451)` we'll take advantage of [assignment without declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration) and proceed like so:

```
let my_a, my_b, my_c;

switch (true) {
    case Math.random() < 0.5:
        ({a: my_a, b: my_b, c: my_c} = myFn(Math.random()));
        console.log('called at one point', my_a, my_b, my_c);
    default:
        ({a: my_a, b: my_b, c: my_c} = myFn(Math.random()));
        console.log('called at another point', my_a, my_b, my_c);
}
```

The question is then, how can I declare/extract the types of `my_a`, `my_b` etc when I know what they're going to be and don't want to manually type them out? [Here's a playground snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGJhgXhgCgIYCcDmAXDGAK5wBGAprgJToB8MA3gFAwcy5VSm6ptOQmNmIBGGAGoRBADTthHCsQDkFFVJn55ijsGKZM9NE2ZcefVHnyaVwFQF9aRhRwet3rADY94CAPrYsn7%20FMGI-sAA3KysEADuAJZQwAAWWFC4pFT0gpzA2BBUMACy2FCpAHS42GAAJiBwRjAAPDAADJUArISuwpjMoiFBMMohYTD6IcAO6H4omGUV1bUNTbQbMbqT4BAgPpVeIPiYdthePnUisODFAA4giWBQKuEBIxETEcC0W5x1VAAZthSF4oL1tgMhhERmNPsEpt9ZhhEAsllUavVGkZNn0hKBIPsqIdjqcChcqFdyiIwCAKjQYA8ni83oFWV8Aj8Yg4gA).

---

**ELABORATION**

What I'm looking for is a way to declare the types when I initialize the vars using

```
let my_a, my_b, my_c;
```

based on what I know about the signature of `myFn` to prevent

```
Variable 'my_a' implicitly has an 'any' type,
but a better type may be inferred from usage. ts(7043)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? if you hover over `my_a` in the `console.log` in the playground, you can see it is inferring up the correct type. I'm having trouble understanding what problem your code is demonstrating, or what you want from it instead.

Comment: Sure, check my edit.

Comment: @AlexWayne at the end of the day I'm trying to prevent `Variable 'my_a' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage. ts(7043)`. I suppose, though, I should not be rewriting global vars in the first place and rather use anonymous fns like Ovidijus suggests in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63943027/8160318?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to explicitly type the `my_*` variables ahead of time, then you can do that by drilling into the return type of your function.

```
let my_a: ReturnType<typeof myFn>['a'],
    my_b: ReturnType<typeof myFn>['b'],
    my_c: ReturnType<typeof myFn>['c'];
```

`typeof myFn` gets the function type from the `myFn` so the type system can work with it. `ReturnType<...>` will get the type that function returns. And, lastly, `['a']` will get the `a` property from that return type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGJhgXhgCgIYCcDmAXDGAK5wBGAprgJToB8MA3gFAwcy5VSm6ptOQmNmIBGGAGoRBADTthHCsQDkFFVJn55ijsGKZM9NE2ZcefVHnyaVwFQF9aRhRwet3rADY94CAPqiMABKFvwAKggADlQAPFDRVCAAZn4oDADaKtgqALo6nIj+yiFhYJEx8YkpaWCZankFHEX6pbwRiVUxNYjpWfa5ANysrBAA7gCWUMAAFlhQuKRU9IKcwNgQVDAAsthQMwB0uNhgACYgcEYwsTAADAcArISuwpjMQUXYsjAlRRTfrRaDnQtUwu32RxO50utFhw10MFAkBAPgOXhA+EwdmwXh8pxEsHAWyiIAmYCgKm+nypAX+fn8wFo8M4pyoyWwpC8UGeCLeHwCXx+xD+AOFAWAwIwvTAYL2h2OZwuRjhLyESIgKKoaIxWPWuKo+L2IjAIH2NBgJLJFJpgRtdJaTI8QA)

---

This isn't really required though. Your playground snippet infers everything correctly and raises no type errors. So I would think about whether this is really necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I've been looking for! As to your edit: it does infer it correctly only upon/after destructuring, not before: https://prnt.sc/uj2lk3

Comment: So what? If you add a `console.log(my_a)` directly below those declarations you'll see the type as `undefined`, which is correct at that point. Typescript is keeping track of when which type is correct and doing the right thing.

Comment: Certainly. I'm not saying TS was wrong -- I'm saying I needed var types upon declaration so that they're _not_ `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So if you explicitly type each one, then TS will throw `Variable 'my_a' is used before being assigned.(2454)` if you reference it before assignment instead of just allowing it to be (temporarily) `undefined`. If that's what you want, I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: Why would that be? I thought only `'const' declarations must be initialized`?

Comment: If you let typescript infer the type, then a `let` can be undefined until it's assigned, and then it has whatever type it could have been assigned. But when you specify the type, then it must be consistent with that type everywhere it's used. And if you use `const` it requires you to initialize it right away. However, with `let` and an explicit type it allows you to initialize it later, you just can't _use_ it until you do.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an interface and place your switch logic inside anonymous arrow functions:

```
interface Alphabet {
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c: string,
}

const myFn = (arg: number): Alphabet =>  {
    return {
        a: 1 + arg,
        b: 'b' + arg,
        c: (() => { return arg + 'c'})()
    }
}

let my_a, my_b, my_c;

switch (true) {
    case Math.random() < 0.5:
        () => {
            const {a: my_a, b: my_b, c: my_c}: Alphabet = myFn(Math.random());
            console.log('called at one point', my_a, my_b, my_c);
        }
    default:
        () => {
            const {a: my_a, b: my_b, c: my_c}: Alphabet = myFn(Math.random());
            console.log('called at one point', my_a, my_b, my_c);
        }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of anonymous functions. But that only solves the problem of the var redeclaration, not the actual question -- rephrased in the question edit. Also, I don't need the globally declared `let my_a, my_b, my_c;` then so your solution only isolates the vars -- which is perfectly acceptable btw.